# Unexpected sort order in Swift's `sorted(by:)`

Tags: swift, sorting

I've a dictionary with the keys being indices into some other arrays and the values being the parent indices of those keys.
I want to sort these keys such that parents come before their children.

I've come up with the following (rather simple) code, which I believe should give the proper sort ordering, but the ordering appears to be rather random instead:

```
let parents: [Int: [Int]] = [2: [],
                             4: [5, 21],
                             5: [21],
                             6: [],
                             9: [],
                             10: [],
                             21: []]

let sortedKeys = Array(parents.keys)
    .sorted { lhs, rhs in
        return parents[rhs]!.contains(lhs)
    }
```

In the result array I would expect '21' to always come before '5', which should always come before '4'. The order and interleaving of the other items doesn't matter.
Instead, the following is a possible result: `[9, 2, 5, 4, 6, 10, 21]`, where the '21' is in the wrong spot.

As far as I understand this code it should follow the rules of giving a *strict weak ordering*.

Why is the ordering not as expected?

Comment: I got this: https://pastebin.com/APJMm4Fj but I'm still wondering if that's the correct order as it seems still unclear to me.

Comment: I *think* (struggling to conceptualise it in my head!) the problem is due to the unordered nature of dictionary keys, and in particular the starting point. Using a loop around `Array(parents.keys.shuffled)` to randomise the order gives a different answer each time, at least some of which don't meet the "parents before children" predicate.

Comment: @Larme Looks like your suggestion solves the transitive incomparability problem as pointed out by Rob below. I'll run more tests to see what happens when the dataset is bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs say](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/sorted(by:)):

> The predicate must be a *strict weak ordering* over the elements. That
> is, for any elements `a`, `b`, and `c`, the following conditions must hold:
>
> - `areInIncreasingOrder(a, a)` is always `false`. (Irreflexivity)
> - If `areInIncreasingOrder(a, b)` and `areInIncreasingOrder(b, c)`
>   are both `true`, then `areInIncreasingOrder(a, c)` is also `true`.
>   (Transitive comparability)
> - Two elements are *incomparable* if neither is ordered before the
>   other according to the predicate. If `a` and `b` are incomparable, and `b`
>   and `c` are incomparable, then `a` and `c` are also incomparable.
>   (Transitive incomparability)

Your example violates *transitive incomparability.* E.g., 5 and 6 are incomparable, as are 6 and 21, but 5 and 21 are *not* incomparable.

Strictly speaking, the *transitive comparability* and *irreflexivity* are not assured by the algorithm, though the data values in the example are designed such that both of these hold.